# GCP -Apache Beam look previous process data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, apache-beam

I'm making Streaming pipeline in GCP using Beam. for example, i need to convert streaming data based previous data value. For example

```
input
id
---
1
2
3
4
1
2

expected output:
1 - NEW  # since first entry
2 - NEW  # since first entry
3 - NEW  # since first entry
4 - NEW  # since first entry
1- OLD # Already visited
2 - OLD # Already Visited
```

```py
class changeStatus(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
      self.log_table= {}

    def process(self, element):
      if element in self.log_table:
            (element,'Visited')
      else:
          self.log_table[element]= True
          (element,'NEW')

windowed_lines = (
            objects
            | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
            | 'print' >> beam.Map(changeStatus())
```

The issue is every set to data process(60 sec), self.log_table is getting refreshed and it is not keeping previous set data process. For example

R

```
Run 1 
    100
    101
    100
Run 2:
   100
   102
```

I am getting for run 1

```
Run 1 
    100 - NEW
    101 - NEW
    100 - VISITED

RUN 2
   100 - NEW
   102 - NEW
```

which is wrong, since RUN 2 data already we received as part of Run -1 .Please share your idea how to implement this logic. Is there way to implement global variable (keep log_table) in apache beam